# How do we list all files of a shared network directory using python?

Tags: python, networking, directory, tuples, share

How can we list all files on a network shared directory of 2 network server shares, (which each running on Ubuntu SE & Windows SE respectively) in Python and add them to a tuple?

### More Details:

**Server:** Windows SE, Ubuntu SE.

**Client:** Windows 10 Pro, Ubuntu 22.04

**Python 3.10.4**

***Scenario: A*** (Listing a contents of local dir in Windows & Ubuntu)

As per following image, L4  to list dir from Windows 10 Pro client. L6 to list dir from Ubuntu Clent.
[code for dir listing] [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/u2rKY.png)

***Scenario: A1*** (Listing a contents of Network shared dir in Windows & Ubuntu)

***A1_0***

In case of both ends are windows env, following code is working; and gives lists of contents from the SERVER_SHARED_PATH (in L2).

```
import os
dir_path = r'//SERVER_IP/FILE_PATH/'
doc_path = os.listdir(dir_path)
doc_path_tuple = tuple(doc_path)
print(doc_path_tuple)
```

***A1_1***

In case, mixed env ( server is Windows SE & Client is Ubuntu DE), then following (python) code from Ubuntu DE gives lists of contents from the Windows SE SERVER_SHARED_PATH.

***#help with python code needed for this to be clarified further***

***A1_2***

In case, mixed env ( server is Ubuntu SE & Client is Windows 10 Pro), then following (python) code from Windows 10 Pro gives lists of contents from the Ubuntu SE SERVER_SHARED_PATH.

***#help with python code needed for this to be clarified further***

###### Thank You to everyone, who is contributing their knowledge to complete this Answer.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Question updated with more details, which will help to clarify further in this regard.